# Symfony routing authentication

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

just a bit of background I'm front-end, but wanted to play about with symfony.

I'm not sure i'm going about this the right way, so abit of guidance would be appreciated!

Alot of the guides I find online are for older versions and don't help me, and some of the terms I see I'm not familar with.

What I am trying to achieve is a user entity and a company entity. When a company is registered, a subdomain is created and the user can login and be redirected there.

When a user lands on a user generated subdomain, it should check if the user is logged in, if the subdomain exists and if the user has access to view the page. Whilst I have achieved this, i'm not sure it's the best way.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Company;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    private $host;
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Matches / exactly
     *
     * @Route("/", name="dashboard")
     * @Route("/dashboard")
     */
    public function dashboardAction(Request $request)
    {

        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       $status = $this->userAuthorized($request);

           switch ($status) {
                case 'anon':
                    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('login'));
                    break;

                case 'nosite':
                    return $this->render('error/nosite.html.twig');
                   break;

                case 'noauth':
                    return $this->render('error/noauth.html.twig');
                    break;
            }

        return $this->render('manager/dashboard.html.twig', array(

        ));
    }


    public function userAuthorized($request)
    {
        // Get user object, subdomain and host
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $host = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
        $subdomain = str_replace('.totalblu.com', '', $host);

        //Check the user is logged in, redirect to login if not.
        if ( $user === "anon."){
            return "anon";
        }

        //Check company exists
        $siteExists = 
        $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')
            ->checkSiteExists($subdomain);
        ;

        if ( !$siteExists ){
            return "nosite";
        }

        $isAuth = 
        $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')
            ->checkUserIsAuthorized($subdomain, $user->getId())
        ;

        if ( !$isAuth ){
            return "noauth";
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Company;

/**
 * CompanyRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class CompanyRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function getAuthorizedUsers()
    {
        return $this->_em
               ->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')
               ->findOneBy(array('companyName' => $subdomain));
    }

    public function checkSiteExists( $subdomain)
    {
        $return = $this->_em
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')
                ->findOneBy(array('companyName' => $subdomain))
        ;

        return count($return) <= 0 ? false : true;
    }

    public function checkUserIsAuthorized($subdomain, $userID)
    {
        $return = $this->_em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')
            ->findBy( array('companyName' => $subdomain, 'user' => $userID) );

        return count($return) <= 0 ? false : true;
    }
}
```

I don't want to have to use the switch statement each time I define a new route, if I could just run the code above when the host contains a subdomain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A controller filter is called after the controller is determined but before the controller action is called.  You can do the checkSiteExists and checkUserIsAuthorized here and toss an exception.  Let the exception handler take care of rendering the error.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html  The anon stuff really should be done by the security system.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the reply, it did helped with my problem.